# Go 1.13: gcc-5 not in PATH

Tags: go, gcc, installation

I've installed **Go 1.13.4** in Debian Linux 10 using **brew**, package `golang` (previously I've removed `golang-1.11` installed via **apt**). It follows `brew info` output.

```
$ brew info golang
go: stable 1.13.4 (bottled), HEAD
Open source programming language to build simple/reliable/efficient software
https://golang.org
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.13.4 (9,271 files, 408.1MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-12-07 at 14:31:52
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/blob/master/Formula/go.rb
==> Requirements
Required: macOS is required ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 1,571 (30 days), 8,628 (90 days), 31,650 (365 days)
install-on-request: 784 (30 days), 4,096 (90 days), 13,267 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

When I try to execute `go build` on a package with code calls `native OS functions`, **GO compiler** tells that it's unable to find `gcc-5` command as presented below.

```
$ go build
# _/home/giacomo/src/goproc/process
exec: "gcc-5": executable file not found in $PATH
```

So I've installed latest **GCC (9.2.1)** from **testing** (deb `http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free`) repository and created a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9`.

This solved the problem. But the question is: is this the correct way to fix the problem? Or is there a place to properly configure the **GCC** used by *golang*?

Any clarification very appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use a Debian package for `go`?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Not really an answer as what you asked is hardly a real question—see below.)

There's multiple points which seem wrong with your situation; let's consider them all.

The first thing to consider is that "Go" means two things: a *language* which has certain syntax and semantics, and one of *implementations* of it.

Go-the-language has at least two mature implementations: the "reference" one—available from the Go's [main site](https://golang.org/dl)—and another one—a part of the GCC. Stock contemporary Debian distribution (Debian 10, "Buster") ships both of them: [`golang-go`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/golang-go) is the former and [`gccgo`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gccgo) is the latter.

As you can see, it's not clear which one you've installed, in the first place.

The second thing to consider is that the reference implementation (dubbed `gc` by its original developers for the reasons I forgot) is completely free-standing (and even self-bootstrapping) and does not use any C compiler (from GCC or other) to build Go code. Conversely, `gccgo` naturally uses other parts of the GCC toolchain to build the Go code.

Still, Go code features a special subsystem called [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) which can be use to interface Go code with code written in C (and with compiled libraries adhering to the C API. When building a program which uses `cgo`, both Go suites *do* rely on at least a C compiler (and may be linker—I don't know this for sure), and by default `gc` expects to be able to use a GCC-compatible compiler, and naturally, `gccgo` uses the C compiler of GCC, too.

Let's now recap a bit.

As you should supposedly see by now, you at least ought to sort several things for you:

- What implementation of Go you're talking about (and/or want installed)?
- Is what you have installed by `brew` is really what you intended to get?
- Does the code you're trying to build use `cgo`?

The fourth thing to consider is why on Earth have you decided to use a kludge invented to help Mac users compensate for the lack of package management system on their platform to deal with packages in Debian.

Debian already ships Go; if you're not satisfied with the its packaged version (1.11), it looks simpler to merely grab the latest-and-greatest binary package from https://golang.org/dl, unack it and use.

Another thing to consider is that since version 1.5 Go is self-bootstrapping because it's written in Go, so if you want to have the latest upstream version, you can just `apt install golang-go` — to have *some* version of Go installed — and then use it to build the latest one, like this:

1. Get the Go source code:

   ```
   $ cd ~
   $ mkdir golang
   $ git clone https://github.com/golang/go golang
   ```
2. Pick the version you want to build:

   ```
   $ cd golang
   $ git checkout go1.13.5
   $ cd src
   $ ./make.bash
   ```
3. Then make sure you have `/home/user/golang/bin` listed in your `$PATH`.

Note that building Go is lightning-fast: on a laptop with SSD it builds from cold start in under a minute.

Comment: This make things more clear, thank you @kostix! I started worked again on Go with a project started 3 years ago and needed to have it compile on linux. I was not aware about different go implementations, but now I can proceed with increased awareness.

Comment: I want to add that I've removed **gcc 9/testing** and **golang** insalled with **brew**. Now installing **gcc** and **golang** from **apt** I'm able to *go build* without any problem.

Comment: Glad you have it sorted out! ;-) Still, please consider not using non-Debian tools to install packages on Debian. It's better to ask a question on unix.stackexchange.com, tagged `debian` before trying to break an otherwise working system ;-)

Comment: @kostik OK, thanks explaining it. I was so happy in OS X that I've installed it in Debian. But now I understand that could be useful only for *secondary* software. Not for import part like a full compiler ecosystem.

Answer (score 21):

Since it looks like you have installed `go` with linuxbrew, you can also install `gcc-5`:

```
brew install gcc@5
```

This solves the problem for me cleanly.

Answer (score 12):

got this issue in linuxbrew. to fix run:

```
go env -w CC=gcc CXX="g++"
```

This uses the system gcc/g++ instead of the ones from linuxbrew

Comment: I wonder what else linuxbrew changes that we don't know about that leads to unforseen consequences.

Comment: More than I like: `GOROOT="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.18.1/libexec"` and `GOTOOLDIR="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.18.1/libexec/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"` so it simply replaced my system's Go paths. Unacceptable. At least the env vars are restored when `brew uninstall go`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option to try is setting the `CC` environment variable to `gcc`.

Comment: Simplest, cleanest solution. Worked well for me on Debian!

Answer (score 0):

An answer based on nemo's answer.

If you have Go installed via the system's package manager
and you installed linuxbrew on that system
and somehow, in my case I installed `buf` via brew,
linuxbrew's go package was pulled in,
you system's Go package was replaced by brew's Go package.

So in order to use your system's Go package again you have to uninstall brew's Go package.

`brew uninstall go`

or if you want to keep brew's Go package, do what nemo answered:

`go env -w CC=gcc CXX="g++"`